C# How to embedded WPF(.exe) to Window Form panel
I have created a Window Form project use for embedded WPF(.exe) to the Panel.
when program run.
the WPF(.exe) can be embedded to the Panel but position of mouse is incorrect.
The WPF(.exe) is no function.
What should I modify to make it work normally?
thanks!!!
namespace iPrint
{
    public partial class FrmiPrint : Form
    {
        private const int GWL_STYLE = (-16);
        private const uint WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong")]
        static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, uint dwNewLong);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetParent")]
        public static extern int SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool BRePaint);

        Process MyProcess = new Process();
        public FrmiPrint()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            PnlEmbedded.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;//panel
            try
            {
                string path = @"C:\Users\User2\Documents\app\QuickSt.exe";

                // open WPF  "QuickSt.exe"                 
                MyProcess.StartInfo.FileName = path;
                MyProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
                MyProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
                MyProcess.Start();
                MyProcess.WaitForInputIdle();
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Open File Error" + ex.Message);
                Environment.ExitCode = 2;
                Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode);
            }
            this.Disposed += (s, a) =>
            {
                MyProcess.Close();
                MyProcess.Dispose();
            };
        }

        private void FrmiPrint_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            // WPF "QuickSt.exe"  embedded  to PnlEmbedded(Panel)
            var handle = MyProcess.MainWindowHandle;
            SetWindowLong(handle, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE);
            SetParent(handle, PnlEmbedded.Handle);
            MoveWindow(handle, 0, 0, PnlEmbedded.Width, PnlEmbedded.Height, true);
        }
    }
}

